# How to interpolate an array in 'awk'?

Tags: arrays, awk, interpolation

we would like to interpolate data within in array using 'awk'. I have an array

```
1 1 3 3 ...
3 3 5 3
5 5 6 5
6 6 6 5
```

for which we would like to obtain

```
1 1 3 3 ...
2 2 4 4
3 3 5 3
4 4 5.5 4
5 5 6 5
6 6 6 5
```

Doing so would allow us to have a complete array covering all possible data  for the first column, representing a timeline. Column 2 and more are data. The matrix is of size of 4x110100. We have this script:

```
awk '
{
  P[$1]=$2
  I[i++]=$1
} 
END{
  j=0; s=I[j]; t=I[j+1]
  for(i=m;i<=n;i++){
    if(I[j+2] && i>t){
    j++; s=I[j]; t=I[j+1]
    }                        
  print i,P[s]+(i-s)*(P[t]-P[s])/(t-s)
  }                                     
}' m=1 n=6 f1.dat > f2.dat
```

but it only does it for the first two columns as

```
1 1 
2 2 
3 3 
4 4 
5 5 
6 6
```

How could we extend the interpolation to the entire array?! I have tried with 'for' or 'while' scripts, but we cannot achieve the aim...

Comment: Why is the second output record `2 2 4 4`, not `2 2 4 3`?

Comment: Oups... you are rigth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by keeping track of just the current and previous lines:

```
BEGIN {
    # initialise "previous" line
    getline;
    for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) p[i] = $i;
}
{
    # print previous line
    print p[0];

    # check if column 1 has skipped
    if ( (d = $1-p[1]) > 1 ) {

        # if so, insert (d-1) new rows
        for (i=1; i<d; i++) {

            # interpolate values for each column
            for (c=1; c<=NF; c++) {
                printf "%s%s",
                    p[c] + (i/d)*($c-p[c]), # linear interpolation
                    c==NF ? ORS : OFS;      # avoid trailing spaces
            }
        }
    }

    # update previous line
    for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) p[i] = $i;
}
END {
    # print the final line
    print p[0];
}
```